# Set python loglevel depending on developing or releasing an app

Tags: python

I am developing a tool and play around with it while developing by having it pip installed with the `-e` editable option. While developing I have set the log level to debug.

I am sure I am going to forget setting the logger to another level as soon as I am going to release the app. Is there a way to put the loglevel inside the `setup.py` file or something ?

Comment: You can define os variable either indicating if it's dev or prod env or directly specifying the log level value.

Answer (score 0):

Log level is controlled in the code, so no, not really.

My solution would be to set the log level to warning by default, and check an environment variable to set it to debug, and then set that locally when you want it.